# PL/SQL load script from file

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, encoding

I need to load a big portion of data using inserts in multiple `.sql` files. I'm creating those files with application using :

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path, true, Encoding.ASCII))
                    {
                        file.WriteLine(text);
                    }
```

Where path is file path and text its another insert going into this file.  Now I have a problem loading those inserts in Oracle SQL Developer using command:

```
@"C:\Users\Desktop\inserts1.sql"
```

because developer change polish characters like `ć`, `ó` into other characters.

Is the problem inside my app to create different files with different encoding or there is a way to load that properly in Developer.

Comment: Your file contains a bunch of insert commands?  If so, don't do that.  Leverage the power of OCI by using ODP.net and do the inserts directly from your C# app -- and use bulk inserts and bind variables (parameters).  The shared pool and your DBA will thank you.  As an aside, your issues with Unicode will likely also disappear.

Comment: Also, I couldn't help but notice that you've explicitly declared Encoding.ASCII...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `Encoding.ASCII` use `Encoding.Default` (this is ANSI Encoding).